# Website Load time - Is India based server responsible

Tags: performance, optimization, time, web, loading

My website has nearly all the traffic from India so I decided to go with an India based VPS because I was told that it would reduce the load time. Although it was costly than US based server I signed up for it. Now I am facing an issue that whenever I check the load time from pingdom or GTMetrix they give me more than 12 secs but when I visit from my office or home PC it takes very less time.

Do you think that pingdom and GTMetrix are giving wrong time because the isp they use to test is US based. Is there any way that I can find out the load time from my PC using my internet connection/ISP. Which I can download and install and which uses my internet connection to perform load test?

My server IP is 103.14.96.209 and 
Domain is muthootfinance.com

Also If i ping it using cmd command the ping time is only 32secs but if I ping using online services like pingdom the ping time comes more than 300 secs. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response times are much faster when pinging from an Indian machine (see here &vaction=ping&ping=start">http://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/ping.php?vtt=1380725309&varghost=103.14.96.209&vhost=&vaction=ping&ping=start)